# Combobox selectedindex =-1 also deletes the text written in the editable combobox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

The problem is when I make the selectedindex=-1, it deletes the text written in the combobox. I only want to deselect the item in the dropdown list but the text should remain written in the comboxbox text area.

I also tried using the selecteditem=null but it also has the same behaviour. I am adding my project below.

I am using input validation and enter key command, so all the results are considered after pressing enter.

please let me know if more details are required.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel : ValidateObservableObject
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.ErrorsChanged += RaiseCanExecuteChanged;
    }

    private void RaiseCanExecuteChanged(object sender, DataErrorsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.HasErrors)
        {
            ItemSelected = -1;  //It also deletes the text written in the combobox
        }

        else
        {
            Locations.Add(Location);
            SelectedLocation = Location;

        }
    }

    private int _itemSelected;

    public int ItemSelected
    {
        get => _itemSelected;
        set
        {
            _itemSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemSelected");
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand _comboBoxEnterKeyCommand;

    public RelayCommand ComboxBoxEnterKeyCommand => _comboBoxEnterKeyCommand ?? (_comboBoxEnterKeyCommand = new RelayCommand(EnterPress));

    private void EnterPress(object obj)
    {
        Location = (string) obj;


    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _locations;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Locations
    {
        get { return _locations ?? (_locations = new ObservableCollection<string>()); }
        set
        {
            _locations = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Locations));
        }
    }


    private string _location;

    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Special characters not allowed")]
    public string Location
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _location, value);
        }
    }

    private string _selectedLocation;

    public string SelectedLocation
    {
        get { return _selectedLocation; }
        set
        {
            _selectedLocation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedLocation));
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Margin="10" x:Name="Combobox" IsEditable="True" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path = ItemSelected}" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
        <ComboBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ComboxBoxEnterKeyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Combobox,Path=Text}" Key="Enter"/>
        </ComboBox.InputBindings>
        <ComboBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Location" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors="True" Mode="TwoWay" />
        </ComboBox.Text>
        <ComboBox.VerticalContentAlignment>Center</ComboBox.VerticalContentAlignment>
        <ComboBox.IsTextSearchEnabled>False</ComboBox.IsTextSearchEnabled>
        <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
            <Binding Path="SelectedLocation" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  />
        </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you sure your requirement makes any sense? It's a standard, expected by users, behavior, that the selected item on a drop-down is in sync with the displayed item.

Comment: yes it should be in sync, thats not the problem. The problem is e.g. I select an "Item1" from the dropdown list and this "item1" text is also shown in the combobox text. Thats alright with me.
the problem is when the user starts typing something after this text e.g. "item1t", now what I want is that the item is deselected from the dropdown list and the text in the combobox still remains "item1t". 
when I deselect the item in the dropdown list using Selectedindex or selecteditem property, it deselects the item in the dropdown list but it also deletes the text in the combobox text field.

Comment: please let me know if u need more clarification

Comment: Then do not set ItemSelected to -1 in code behind, but just leave your event handler. When the edited value is not on the list, the dropdown list is deselected automatically, and the selection is back, when the value is on the list.